# How do I configure a new SQL Server login for authentication using Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, authentication, ssms

I just installed Visual Studio 2010, and by default it installs the SQL Server 2008. I don't have sql management.

I don't know the login and password of the sql server when I try to create a new Database using SQL Server Authentication. I read that since I just installed the VS 2010, so I need to create a login, but I don't find how to do it using VISUAL STUDIO. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough it's not important to set the authentication mode to server authentication in the development stage. as you'll change the `Connection String` to your deployment server settings. so by then, you could add the authentication type and the user and password very easily and it won't affect your code .. PS: make sure you save your ConnectionString in one place and reuse it all over your application (Ex. Web.Config)

But if you really need to have the server authentication enabled now, you'll need [the management studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en). and [here](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2008/04/03/Enabling-Mixed-Mode-Authentication-in-SQL-Server.aspx)'s an article on how it's done through the management studio.

---

**Edit**

I found this nice article, it will solve your problem without having to download the management studio .. [There you go](http://vakul.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/configure-microsoft-sql-server-for-mixed-mode-authentication/)

Comment: I will check that tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. I decided to install the management studio =). And then I followed your tutorial and did some stuff to resolve.

Comment: I thought the management studio was a better and a more clean solution .. Glad I could help =D